# h:commandLink on render shows org.apache.myfaces though it's ibm faces which has been used

Tags: jsf

This is a peculiar thing that i have observed. I have a `h:commandLink` inside a `h:datatable`. The commandLink code looks like this :

```
<h:commandLink value="#{grease.greaseId}" rendered="#{MyBean.btnName == 'ending'}" id="greaseNo1" action="#{MyBean.greaseIdMonitored}" immediate="true">
     <f:param name="id" value="#{grease.greaseId}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

This is rendered as the following html :

```
<script src="/grease/faces/javax.faces.resource/oamSubmit.js?ln=org.apache.myfaces" type="text/javascript">&lt;!--
//--&gt;</script><a id="myForm:dt1:0:greaseNo1" onclick="return myfaces.oam.submitForm('myForm','myForm:dt1:0:greaseNo1',null,[['id','mylot-256987']]);" href="#">mylot-256987</a>
```

What i don't understand is why is there a reference to `org.apache.myfaces` ? I am not using myfaces, rather it's ibm faces.

Any help in understanding the problem is appreciated .

Comment: IBM extends the Apache libraries, so MyFaces, OpenJPA, etc, in JSF 2.0 you can put your resources in a folder with the name "resource" and use it resources with the library attribute in your control tags, then in this is case is when you see that url, but I can't see you are using any resource. As @Sence says it must be an script file that the IBM extension of MyFaces requires and this implementation add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [WAS documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.express.iseries.doc/ae/cweb_jsfmigrate.html):

> In WebSphere® Application Server V8.0 and later, the default JavaServer Faces (JSF) implementation has changed to MyFaces.

There is no IBM Faces as such (though IBM has proprietary component libraries and extensions.) IBM has always based their JSF implementations on either the licensed reference implementation or open source software. See the [WAS 8.5 documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/tweb_jsf.html) on how to configure the platform's JSF engine.

Comment: Ahh... that may be the reason.. I am using RAD and WAS 8.5.. , that's why i am seeing that js getting rendered..Thanks i did not know that.

Answer (score 0):

the oamSubmit.js file is located inside a resource folder, called org.apache.myfaces
Take a look at the implementation file.

Comment: I don't have any impl as such .

Comment: as you see, you have :-)

Comment: It seems i do.. But i did not understand what you were telling because it was not explained in detail. However, i appreciate your effort, thank you .